# How to handle multiple components using the same v-model value

Tags: vue.js

What I am trying to create is a dropdown menu where if a user selects "other" they are prompted to enter a custom value. I am struggling to figure out how to do this in vue

```
                <select
                class="text-gray-700 outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full border focus:ring-opacity-75 rounded-md px-3 py-2 mb-2 bg-white "
                v-model="form.campaign_target"
            >
                <option
                    v-for="target in campaign_targets"
                    :value="target.id"
                    :key="target.id"
                >
                    {{ target.name }}
                </option>
                <option>Other</option>
            </select>

            <div v-if="form.campaign_target === 'Other'">
                <label class="font-semibold text-gray-700 text-sm mb-2 block">Enter Campaign Target</label>
                <input
                type="text"
                class="text-gray-700 outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full border focus:ring-opacity-75 rounded-md px-3 py-2 bg-white"
                v-model="form.campaign_target"
                />
            </div>
```

Which sort of makes sense until as soon as I edit the custom value the label disappears because the value isn't "other" anymore....

The solution to this I can think of would be to create two variables to bind using v-model like "campaign_targets_custom" and "campaign_targets_standard" and then assign the value of form.campaign_target based on them. However there's lots of complexities like making sure if campaign_targets_standard becomes blank and a "campaign_target_standard" is not selected than form.campaign_targets has to be null otherwise other stuff in the code breaks.

This seems like it might be a common problem so wondering if there is some solution I am missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not solve it using only one `campaign_target` variable in simple way.

And I would suggest to keep it as simple as possible ([KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)).

Use two variables for input and a computed value for `campaign_target` variable.

Here is the playground.

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;

const App = {
  data() {
    return {
      form: {        
        campaign_target_type: null,
        campaign_target_other: null
      },
      campaign_targets: [ 
      { id: 1, name: 'One'},
      { id: 2, name: 'Two'}, 
      { id: 3, name: 'Three'}
      ]    
    }
  },
  computed: {
    campaign_target() {
      return this.form.campaign_target_type == 'Other' 
        ? this.form.campaign_target_other 
        : this.form.campaign_target_type
    }
  }  
}

const app = createApp(App)
const vm = app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 2; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>
  <select v-model="form.campaign_target_type">
    <option
        v-for="target in campaign_targets"
        :value="target.name"
        :key="target.id"
    >
        {{ target.name }}
    </option>
    <option>Other</option>
  </select>

  <div v-if="form.campaign_target_type === 'Other'">
      <label class="font-semibold text-gray-700 text-sm mb-2 block">Enter Campaign Target</label>&nbsp;
      <input type="text" v-model="form.campaign_target_other" />
  </div>
  <p>campaign_target: {{ campaign_target }}</p>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```